# Getting WebKit bindings to work with Perl and gkt2

Tags: perl, webkit, cpan, gtk2

I need to use WebKit in my perl + gtk2 application. Found a package Gtk2::WebKit on CPAN, but can't get it working.

```
cpan> install Gtk2::WebKit
```

gives following output:

```
Package webkit-1.0 was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `webkit-1.0.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'webkit-1.0' found
at inc/Module/Install/PRIVATE/WebKit.pm line 24
*** can not find package webkit-1.0
*** check that it is properly installed and available in PKG_CONFIG_PATH
at inc/Module/Install/PRIVATE/WebKit.pm line 24
No 'Makefile' created'YAML' not installed, will not store persistent state
FLORA/Gtk2-WebKit-0.09.tar.gz
/usr/bin/perl Makefile.PL INSTALLDIRS=site -- NOT OK
Running make test
Make had some problems, won't test
Running make install
Make had some problems, won't install
Failed during this command:
FLORA/Gtk2-WebKit-0.09.tar.gz                : writemakefile NO -- No 'Makefile' created
```

It looks as if cpan wasn't able to find webkit, but I'm not sure how to fix that (my first time using perl and cpan).

Env: perl 5.12.4, ubuntu 11.10

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Install `libwebkitgtk-devel`: `sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-devel`.

Answer (score 6):

sudo apt-get install libwebkitgtk-dev

Answer (score 5):

For Debian/Ubuntu and similar, the package name to install is **libwebkitgtk-dev**.
For OpenSuse and other RPM-based systems, the package name is **libwebkitgtk-devel**.